# TypeError: auth is not a function after logging in or signing up

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error after trying to either sign up or login as a pop up

```
localhost:3000 says TypeError: _auth_base_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.default.auth is not a function
```

I'm not sure where the problem is coming from but if you need here is my login page

```
const Login = ({ history }) => {
  const handleLogin = useCallback(
    async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
      try {
        await app
          .auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
        history.push("/");
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    },
    [history]
  );

  // var { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  // if (currentUser) {
  //   return <Redirect to="/" />;
  // }
```

and here is my signup page:

```
const SignUp = ({ history }) => {
  const handleSignUp = useCallback(
    async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
      try {
        await app
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
        history.push("/");
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    },
    [history]
  );
```

Sorry for asking too much but I have looked everywhere and tried every possible solution, but none worked for me.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". A title that is just an error message is not helpful.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok sorry i had edited would you please look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by routing the files to the required pages